# Search up include hierarcy

Tags: c, eclipse

Is there an easy way to do a text search on a c file that goes up the include tree (including files in the include search locations)? Preferably in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

check for ctags, Ctags generates an index (or tag) file of language objects found in source files that allows these items to be quickly and easily located by a text editor or other utility.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

Comment: how does one run ctags on windows?